# Нужна помощь с использованием QCheckBox и QComboBox в циклах

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Есть программа на *Python* с использованием *PyQt5*.

Имеются **3** `QComboBox`:

- `ComboFizAkt` - уровень физической активности, в котором **4** варианта выбора.
- `ComboCel` - цель (хочу похудеть, хочу улучшить фигуру и т.д.), в котором **3** варианта выбора.
- `ComboTrenirovki` - кол-во тренировок в неделю, в котором **7** вариантов выбора.

Также имеются **2** `QCheckBox`, которые отвечают за пол пользователя:

- `PolMuzh` - мужской пол
- `PolZhen` - женский пол

Хочу кое-что реализовать, нужна помощь.

Грубый пример: Если нажата `PolMuzh` и в `ComboFizAkt` выбран  пункт "Преобладает физ. труд", вывести print(123)

```
# текст combobox'ов
self.LvlFizAkt.setText("Уровень физической активности:")   # qlabel
self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText("Сидячий")
self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText("Слабый физ. труд")
self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText("Преобладает физ. труд")
self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText("Тяжёлый физ. труд")
self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText("Очень тяжёлый физ. труд")
self.ViborCeli.setText("Ваша цель:")                       # qlabel
self.ComboCel.setItemText("Ничего не хочу")
self.ComboCel.setItemText("Хочу похудеть")
self.ComboCel.setItemText("Хочу улучшить фигуру")
self.ComboCel.setItemText("Хочу набрать мыш. массу")
self.KolvoTrenirovok.setText("Кол-во тренировок в неделю:") # qlabel
self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText("0")
self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText("1")
self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText("2")
self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText("3")
self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText("4")
self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText("5")
self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText("6")
self.ComboTrenirovki.setItemText("7+")

# функция, при которой, если PolMuzh включён, PolZhen выключается

self.PolMuzh.stateChanged.connect(self.selectCombo1)
self.PolZhen.stateChanged.connect(self.selectCombo2)

def selectCombo1(self, toggle):
    if toggle == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
        self.PolZhen.setEnabled(False)
    else:
        self.PolZhen.setEnabled(True)


# функция, при которой, если PolZhen включён, PolMuzh выключается
def selectCombo2(self, toggle):
    if toggle == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
        self.PolMuzh.setEnabled(False)
    else:
        self.PolMuzh.setEnabled(True)
```

Comment: Кст, а почему QCheckBox для полов? Тут QRadioButton больше подходит, плюс добавляя их (QRadioButton) в группу кнопок автоматически только одна из радиокнопок будет выбранной

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо, учту

Comment: Даже немного не так, просто добавляя кнопки на виджет, они становятся эксклюзивными в пределах виджета-родителя (достаточно на виджет положить, а для групп кнопок можно положить, например, в QGroupBox). А для большего контроля и единообразия можно их еще в QButtonGroup добавить

Comment: @gil9red, хорошо, большое спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Если нажата PolMuzh и в ComboFizAkt выбран пункт "Преобладает физ.
> труд", вывести print(123)

При клике `PolMuzh` проверяйте текущее значение в комбобоксе (это можно сделать через методы: `currentText`, `currentIndex`, `currentData`)

Пример:

```
def selectCombo1(self, toggle):
    if toggle == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
        self.PolZhen.setEnabled(False)

        if self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Преобладает физ. труд':
            print(123)
        
    else:
        self.PolZhen.setEnabled(True)
```